# How to Convert String to Date using MapStruct in Java?

Tags: java, string, date, mapstruct

I am using MapStruct to map values from a source to a target class. The source class has a String property and the target class has a java.util.Date property. The source property is like this: "yyyy-mm-dd". And I want to convert this String property to a Date property. How can I do that using MapStruct? Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

MapStruct takes care of `String` to `Date` conversions automatically. If you need to specify format of your date you can do it like this:

```java
@Mapping(target = "date", dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd")
Destination map(Source source);

//For datetime
@Mapping(target = "date", dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
Destination map(Source source);
```

Where `target = "date"` is the name of your property.
You can find more about this in [MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#datatype-conversions).

Answer (score 1):

[From the official guide](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#invoking-other-mappers), if you have multiple dates, you can use this:

```
public class DateMapper {

    public String asString(Date date) {
        return date != null ? new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" )
            .format( date ) : null;
    }

    public Date asDate(String date) {
        try {
            return date != null ? new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" )
                .parse( date ) : null;
        }
        catch ( ParseException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException( e );
        }
    }
}
```

And after in your mapper:

```
@Mapper(uses=DateMapper.class)
public interface CarMapper {

    CarDto carToCarDto(Car car);
}
```